# Excel: Only Calculating Average Score If The Score Was Entered Within The Last Year (DATEDIF/AVERAGEIF)

Tags: excel

Trying to average scores only if they are within a year of today's date. What I have so far is two columns, one with "Days Since Score" (column E) and another with the average which looks like

`=DATEDIF(C2,(TODAY()),"d")` And `=AVERAGEIF(E2:E20,"<365",D2:D20)`

C column being the dates the scores were entered

D column is the scores

E column is the "Days since today"

**I am trying to eliminate the need for Column E and want to have the formula only in 1 cell.** I have tried this:

`=IF(DATEDIF(C2:C17,(TODAY()),"d")<365,AVERAGE(D2:D17),0)`

but it averages the entire "score" column and outputs it multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=AVERAGEIF(E2:E20,">" & TODAY()-365,D2:D20)
```

Comment: Excellent, this works! Would you mind explaining to me how it is working? I want to also use this to calculate the average of the 2nd year( >=365 & <730 )

Would it look something like:

```=AVERAGEIF(C2:C20,"<" & TODAY()+365 & TODAY()-730,D2:D20)``` ?